# In Iron Man why do Gulmirans speak with Iranian accent?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2008

In the 2008 movie, *Iron Man*, Tony Stark goes with his suit to the fictional city of Gulmira located in Afghanistan to stop the Ten Rings terrorist organization from killing innocent people.

While the city is in Afghanistan its inhabitants speak in Iranian accent. I tell this because I am Iranian myself and I know both Iranian and Afghan accents.

The Persian spoken in Afghanistan has a different accent than in Iran and they even use some different words in some sentences.

I know the actors playing Gulmira parts were Iranian. But the filmmakers could simply hire Afghan actors to do the lines in order to be realistic and also to not cause controversy (In Iran there are many people who got angered to see Afghans speak in Iranian accent in the movie. They think filmmakers wanted to humiliate their nationality by depicting poor Afghan people who are victims of terror speaking in Iranian accent).

So the question: Why did Gulmirans speak in Iranian accent while they were Afghans? Did the filmmakers had something in mind when they decided to use Iranians instead of Afghans?

Update: The Iranian accent that Gulmirans speak is the Tehrani dialect which is spoken in Tehran and Alborz provinces, Iran. In other parts of Iran there are other dialects, but the Afghan accent is not near to any of them.

Comment: This is similar to many other movie criticisms.    For example: A movie depicting a musician may fool most viewers, but actual musicians can see that the music performance is obviously faked.

Comment: And it's safe to say the target audience of the film consists to less than 1% of people from Iran or Afghanistan, nor anybody who sees either of them as particularly culturally threatened or so. Thus the choice of actors would be dominated by practical considerations for the shot, so long as the result is "plausible middle-eastern" for Western audiences. Could be any combination of acting skills, ease of hiring, cost, logistics... I don't know what.

Comment: The same reason Russians don't sound like Russian when they speak in John Wick for example.

Comment: @Clockwork The Russians who don't sound Russian are English speaking actors. For example, look at David Harbour and Florence Pugh in *Black Widow*. But in *Iron Man* they used **Persian** speaking actors but with a wrong accent. If they used to hire Persian speaking actors why didn't they choose Afghans?

Comment: The question is essentially pointless.  They didn't deliberately use the wrong accent.  They just didn't consider it a goal to get the accent right --because essentially no one cares except an infinitessimal fraction of the audience.  No reason to overthink this.   Previous commenters' analogies are apt.  "Why didn't they just hire an actor who spoke Russian?"  "Why didn't they hire someone capable of playing piano?"   Because most people don't know the difference.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - *"Why is this actor portraying a Ukrainian/Russian actually Russian/Ukrainian?"*. Because 99.99% of their audience can't tell the difference, and anyone who can tell the difference isn't their target audience anyway.

Comment: As an Iranian myself, I can pick out the differences in the accents quite easily. However, I don't assume it was used for malicious intentions. I believe it was just a simple casting choice. Iranians can tend to be quick to take offence to things that may not have been intended. Why are Iranians assuming that to be associated with Afghanis is a negative thing?

Comment: @Möoz You are the first Iranian person with high reputation that I met here :)

Comment: Imagine how we northern Brits suffered through 8 seasons of Game of Thrones. Great show, but barely a handful of the Northern Westeros actors could vaguely get the accent right. Notably Jon, who never got any better at it in a decade. We used to jokingly give 'GoT scores', 0-10. Ned & Robert were true 10s [being actually native] Rob got a 9 & he's actually Scottish. Davos got a 9, Irish playing Geordie. Jon never beat a 4.